# Extract the strings using regexp_substr in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, regexp-replace

I use regexp_substr function to extract strings in oracle database. I need to remove only the last string column and print the remaining output.

Thanks in advance

**Original datafile location**

```
SQL> select name from v$datafile;

NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/apps01/oradata/orcl/datafile/o1_mf_system_k45ylzb0_.dbf
/apps01/oradata/orcl/datafile/o1_mf_sysaux_k45yn2fs_.dbf
/apps01/oradata/orcl/datafile/o1_mf_undotbs1_k45ynvjz_.dbf
/apps01/oradata/orcl/datafile/o1_mf_users_k2pmzsw2_.dbf
/apps01/oradata/orcl/datafile/o1_mf_users_k45ynwlp_.dbf
```

I need to remove last string column with *.dbf similar to **awk** in linux

**SQL:**

```
SQL> select regexp_substr(name, '/[A-Z].*$') from v$datafile;

REGEXP_SUBSTR(NAME,'/[A-Z].*$')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/orcl/datafile/o1_mf_system_k45ylzb0_.dbf
/orcl/datafile/o1_mf_sysaux_k45yn2fs_.dbf
/orcl/datafile/o1_mf_undotbs1_k45ynvjz_.dbf
/orcl/datafile/o1_mf_users_k2pmzsw2_.dbf
/orcl/datafile/o1_mf_users_k45ynwlp_.dbf
```

**Expected Output:**

```
NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/apps01/oradata/orcl/datafile/
/apps01/oradata/orcl/datafile/
/apps01/oradata/orcl/datafile/
/apps01/oradata/orcl/datafile/
/apps01/oradata/orcl/datafile/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

- combination of **`SUBSTR()`** and **`INSTR()`** functions by
  searching for **`/`** character reversely through use of **-1** as
  the last parameter for **`INSTR()`**

**or**

- **`REGEXP_REPLACE()`** with **`[^/]+$`** pattern where

  **+** matches one or more occurrences,

  **$** matches the end of a string

as the second method

such as

```sql
SELECT SUBSTR(name,1,INSTR(name,'/',-1)) AS method1,
       REGEXP_REPLACE(name,'[^/]+$') AS method2 
  FROM v$datafile
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=77dc46622055ace175815ee1029e06ee)</kbd>